# client-side react - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build client-side of an app using React with existing server-side code (REST API and database) .

Currently, trying to create a profile view and allowing users to add/remove movies from favourite.
There's movie-card.jsx and movie-view.jsx.

I'm trying to allow user to add/remove movies from user profile under movie-view.

Now user able to add/remove movies. But the problem is after clicking add/remove movies and click go to profile, the error appears.
If i refresh the page and go to profile, the favourite movies list is actually updated.

Another problem is, when updating profile for example, update password. Previously was hashedpassword, after updating, it became not encrypted which when i login after updating, it says no such user.

How do i avoid that?

Provided my github pull link from a new branch.

https://github.com/joannawongww/myFlix-client/pull/4

movie-view.jsx:

```js
import {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./movie-view.scss";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import {
  ProfileView
} from "../profile-view/profile-view";

export const MovieView = ({
  user,
  token,
  movies,
  setUser
}) => {
  const {
    movieId
  } = useParams();
  const [Favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user ? .Favorite ? .length && movieId) {
      setFavorite(user.Favorite.includes(movieId));
    }
    // const isFavorited = user.Favorite.includes(movieId);
    // setFavorite(isFavorited);
  }, [user.Favorite, movieId]);

  const addFavorite = () => {
    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}/movies/${movieId}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFavorite(true);
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(data);
      });
  };

  const removeFavorite = () => {
    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}/movies/${movieId}`, {
          method: "DELETE",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFavorite(false);
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(data);
      });
  };

  const movie = movies.find((movie) => movie.id === movieId);

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    div >
    <
    span >
    <
    img src = {
      movie.ImagePath
    }
    width = "30%" / >
    <
    /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Title: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Title
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Description: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Description
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Genre: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Genre
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Director: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Director
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Featured: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Featured
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    {
      Favorite ? ( <
        Button onClick = {
          removeFavorite
        } > Remove from favourite movies < /Button>
      ) : ( <
        Button onClick = {
          addFavorite
        } > Add to my favorite movies < /Button>
      )
    }

    <
    Link to = {
      `/`
    } >
    <
    Button > Back < /Button> <
    /Link> <
    /div>
  );
};
```

main-view.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MovieCard } from "../movie-card/movie-card";
import { MovieView } from "../movie-view/movie-view";
import { LoginView } from "../login-view/login-view";
import { SignupView } from "../signup-view/signup-view";
import { ProfileView } from "../profile-view/profile-view";
import { NavigationBar } from "../navigation-bar/navigation-bar";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const MainView = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

  const onLogout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.clear();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      return;
    }

    fetch("https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/movies", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);

        const moviesFromApi = data.map((movie) => {
          return {
            id: movie._id,
            Title: movie.Title,
            Description: movie.Description,
            ImagePath: movie.ImagePath,
            Genre: movie.Genre.Name,
            Director: movie.Director.Name,
            Featured: movie.Featured.toString(),
          };
        });
        setMovies(moviesFromApi);
      });
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavigationBar
        user={user}
        onLoggedOut={() => {
          setUser(null);
        }}
      />{" "}
      <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/signup"
            element={
              <>
                {" "}
                {user ? (
                  <Navigate to="/" />
                ) : (
                  <Col md={5}>
                    <SignupView />
                  </Col>
                )}{" "}
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/login"
            element={
              <>
                {" "}
                {user ? (
                  <Navigate to="/" />
                ) : (
                  <Col md={5}>
                    <LoginView
                      onLoggedIn={(user, token) => {
                        setUser(user);
                        setToken(token);
                      }}
                    />{" "}
                  </Col>
                )}{" "}
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/profile"
            element={
              <>
                {" "}
                {!user ? (
                  <Navigate to="/login" replace />
                ) : (
                  <Col>
                    <ProfileView
                      user={user}
                      token={token}
                      setUser={setUser}
                      movies={movies}
                      onLogout={onLogout}
                    />{" "}
                  </Col>
                )}{" "}
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/movies/:movieId"
            element={
              <>
                {" "}
                {!user ? (
                  <Navigate to="/login" replace />
                ) : movies.length === 0 ? (
                  <Col> List is empty! </Col>
                ) : (
                  <Col md={8}>
                    <MovieView
                      movies={movies}
                      user={user}
                      setUser={setUser}
                      token={token}
                    />{" "}
                  </Col>
                )}{" "}
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <>
                {" "}
                {!user ? (
                  <Navigate to="/login" replace />
                ) : movies.length === 0 ? (
                  <Col> List is empty! </Col>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    {" "}
                    {movies.map((movie) => (
                      <Col className="mb-4" key={movie.id} md={3}>
                        <MovieCard movie={movie} />{" "}
                      </Col>
                    ))}{" "}
                  </>
                )}{" "}
              </>
            }
          />{" "}
        </Routes>{" "}
      </Row>{" "}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the effect part is wrong

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isFavorited = user.FavoriteMovies.includes(movieId);
    setFavorite(isFavorited);
  }, []);
```

Here, you have initialized the useEffect with empty dependencies. So it will fire as soon as the component mounts. But you are relaying on the `user` and `movieId` field to generate the `isFavorited` state.

You can solve this either two ways

1. To update dependencies and if condition

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(user?.FavoriteMovies?.length && movieId) {
       setFavorite(user.FavoriteMovies.includes(movieId));
    }
  }, [user.FavoriteMovies, movieId]);
```

2. Using React.useMemo()

```
const Favorited = React.useMemo(() => {
    if(user?.FavoriteMovies?.length && movieId) {
       return user.FavoriteMovies.includes(movieId)
    }
    return false;
},
[user.FavoriteMovies, movieId]);
```

or even shorted

```
const Favorited = React.useMemo(() => 
   (user?.FavoriteMovies || [])?.includes(movieId),
[user.FavoriteMovies, movieId]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.

I am having another issue: now my user able to add/remove movies from favourite. But the problem is that after clicking Add movies to Favourite or Remove movie from favourite and clicking to profile view, an error pop up. But the user profile is actually updated with the movie (either added or removed).

Would you be able to advise further? Will update my qns.

Comment: You need to re-fetch the api again after add/remove. You can use a callback from movie-view to main-view and re-run the things you wrote inside the useEffect in main-view

Comment: Hi, I have tried but still unable to solve it. Would you be able to advise in more details on how to go about going it? Sorry for troubling you as i'm still a student just started learning.